# Change row background color based on the currently active key value of the row?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to change the background color of the row based on the returned key value of the row? I'm doing this project where a row's background color must turn black if that row's key value is currently active in my `this.state.index`.

My code:
[image]

So for example if the `this.state.index` = 0, the background color of row with the key = 0 should change to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add inline css styling:

`style={{backgroundColor: this.state.index === index ? 'black' : null}}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
<tr key={index} className={this.state.index === index ? 'highlight' : ''}>
  ...
</tr>
```

Where `highlight` is a custom css class that sets the colour of the background to black (you can name this whatever you like).

Also unrelated to your question, but I don't think you need to call `slice()` on `this.props.table`, it looks like you should just be able to do `this.props.table.map()`. Currently, `slice()` is just producing a duplicate of the array.